# Javascript array inside of another array (multidimensional)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
cells = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

which is updated with a jQuery function

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
...
    $('#box').click(function(e){

        var indexArray = e.target.id.split('_');

        if (indexArray.length > 1) {
            var index = indexArray[1];

            if (cells[index] == 0){
                cells[index] = move;
...
})
```

I want to make a cross-check of cells array groups.
for example:

```
(cells[0] + cells[1] + cells[2]);   // row 1
(cells[3] + cells[4] + cells[5]);   // row 2
(cells[6] + cells[7] + cells[8]);   // row 3
...
```

I tried to create a multidimensional array, but all I get is undefined:

```
var triggers = [[cells[0], cells[1], cells[2]]];
```

is it possible to pass cells arrays' variables to triggers array?
Can't figure it out?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get part of an array, for example

```
var triggers = [cells.slice(0, 3)];
```

The call `cells.slice(0, 3)` returns an array with the elements of `cells` starting from index `0` up to and *excluding* `3`, i.e. `[cells[0], cells[1], cells[2]]`. You can wrap another array over that "manually" to get the desired result.

Comment: Superb )) this is what i needed.
Only one thing is left ))

I also need to chekUp to diagonals ))

cells[0] + cells[4] + cells[8]
cells[2] + cells[4] + cells[6]

Comment: @A1exandr: That won't be possible with an one-liner unless you write it out manually.